# django LANGUAGE_CODE not working

Tags: django, internationalization, locale

I have a Django 1.9.1 app.  Some of it appears in French, but not all.  When I visit one of my forms, I get some stock phrases in French ("Search" => "Rechercher", "Name" => "Nom"), but not any of my app's phrases (e.g., "Add New Patient", "Caregiver" are both in English).

I have language settings configured:

```
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(
    os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(
    os.path.abspath(__file__)))))

LANGUAGES = [
  ('fr', _('French')),
  ('en', _('English')),
]
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, "locale"),
)
```

I have LocaleMiddleware configured:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    # LocaleMiddleware should be after SessionMiddleware and before CommonMiddleware
    # See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)
```

I have a some translation files that came from "makemessages -l fr" with my phrases translated:

```
locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo
```

I load i18n in my template.

```
{% load i18n %}
```

Some of it is in French, so that shouldn't be the problem anyway.

I am using the [Quick Language Switcher](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-language-switcher/pmjbhfmaphnpbehdanbjphdcniaelfie?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) to send the Accept-Language: HTTP header 'fr'.

The Django debug toolbar shows up in French (!), and says "Accept-Language: fr" in the HTTP request, and "Content-Language: fr" in the HTTP response.  It also says the Django variable LANGUAGE_CODE is "en-us" (?), even though I have that setting commented out.

I have read ["How Django discovers language preference"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference) and I don't see what I'm missing.

Answer (score 2):

My LOCALE_PATH was wrong.  It was one level too high.  Here is the right LOCALE_PATH for me:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(
    os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "locale"),
)
```